# custom soundcloud player (minimal) font color stays black

Tags: css, fonts, soundcloud

Again, moved from github, so sorry for cross-posting.

I have adapted the minimal player and can't get the font color for the title of the tracks to change. All other font attributes change, but the font colour always remains black:

```
.sc-player {
font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
color: grey;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.6em;
font-weight: none;
text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

How do I change the color attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.sc-player ol li a { color:grey; }` should work fine for you
or just `.sc-player a { color:grey; }`

Comment: http://www.bugcompass.bingostarr.co.uk/sc_bugplayer/sc_bugplayer.html and http://www.bugcompass.bingostarr.co.uk/sc_bugplayer/sc-player.css

Comment: change color in sc-player.css line 287
`.sc-player ol.sc-trackslist li.active a { 
color: black;
}` or just add `!important` to your css style.